# how to name a machine in a vmware request from kitchen?

Tags: chef-infra, vmware, test-kitchen

I'm using Kitchen to request items from our vra/vmware host. I can name the "deployment" using the `notes` attribute in the `driver` section. But this cookbook spins 5 servers, and i want to be able to see which is which in the vmware dashboard without jumping through hoops. I just want to put something in the "description" column of each machine's row. I tried putting `notes` in the `suites` section, it didn't fail but didn't do anything.

To put it another way, How do i get text into the `description` field of the **machines** view when using Kitchen?